# how can I catch a redirect and downloading a generated file instead?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

I am creating a plugin which generates a CSV file and allows an admin to download it. I have a working function which generates the CSV data, but I'm having trouble making it downloadable. I have tried the solution from [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/276709/how-to-force-download-a-plugin-generated-file) but it doesn't seem to be catching the redirect. Here is the element that causes the redirect:

```
<form method="GET" action="data.csv">
    <input type="submit" class="button button-primary" value="Download CSV"></input>
</form>
```

This is what I have so far for catching the redirect:

```
function download_redirect() {
   if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']=='/wp-admin/data.csv?') {
       $csv_data = generate_csv();

       header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="data.csv"');
       header('Content-Type: text/csv');
       header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($csv_data));
       header('Connection: close');

       echo $csv_data;
    
       exit();
   }
}
add_action('template_redirect','download_redirect');
```

the function generate_csv() returns the contents of the CSV file as a string. What am I missing?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "catch a redirect"? There is no redirecting going on here, your script is simply returning a response with a non-HTML content-type

Comment: @ADyson I just mean intercepting a GET request and returning the result of the code instead of an actual page, if that makes sense. I may be approaching this in the wrong way, I'm pretty new to plugin development.

Comment: So the issue is that it shows the CSV data in the browser window rather than downloading it, is that right?

Comment: @ADyson no, it just tries to take me to data.csv, which doesn't exist, so I get a 404 page.

Comment: Ah yes. `action="data.csv"` will do that. That needs to point to whatever wordpress URL will trigger your script to run. I can't help thinking there is something missing from that other question in terms of how they engineered a .csv extension to trigger php.

Comment: @ADyson That makes sense. However, I've also tried it with a url ending in php (as well as a url with no extension) and the function still doesn't trigger.

Comment: OK. Well under what conditions do you expect the function to trigger? Is it supposed to fire for every request coming through the webserver, and then check if it matches a specific URL (which is what the code seems to do in the function)? At this point I should say that while i know php and web development very well I'm not a wordpress expert and have no idea what wordpress does with the add_action function. So I'm mainly trying to logic this out.

Comment: @ADyson Yes, that's basically what I'm trying to do. It notices when a request is made for data.php, and returns a csv file generated from a function. add_action() in php defines when the function runs, and from what I've read template_redirect seems to be the hook I want.

Comment: `It notices when a request is made for data.php`...currently it's programmed to request (and detect) data.csv not data.php. Is the problem as simple as that?

Comment: Not sure if it gets to the point where the `template_redirect` hook executes, when you submit to a non-existing(?) URL - might be, that WP's 404 handler interferes before that already. I would try and simply leave the form action attribute empty, so that this targets the current admin page URL you are on, again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you to @CBroe for giving me the idea that finally helped me solve this. I was approaching this in the wrong way. Instead of trying to intercept requests, I was able to use a different hook, updated_option, which runs after options update, and return the CSV file then. Here is what worked:

```
<form method="GET" action="data.csv">
   <input type="submit" class="button button-primary" value="Download CSV"> 
   </input>
</form>
```

And the hook ("eud" is the prefix I am using for all settings):

```
function download_redirect( $option_name ) {
    if (substr($option_name, 0, 3) == "eud"){  //$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']=='/wp-admin/data.csv?') {
       $csv_data = generate_csv();

       header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="data.csv"');
       header('Content-Type: text/csv');
       header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($csv_data));
       header('Connection: close');

       echo $csv_data;
    
       exit();
    }
}
add_action('updated_option','download_redirect');
```